# Start command and provide prompt parameter

Tags: command-line

I have a command that builds things and then provides an interactive shell through prompt (eg type R to restart, Q to quit, ...).

I would like to use that command but stop it once it reaches the prompt part. Is there a way to either pass the "Q" argument when calling my command, or killing it once it reaches the prompt?

Comment: Assuming that your prompt is just calling 'read', just `echo Q | your-command`

Comment: @JeffSchaller: perfect, do you want to add it as an answer so that I can mark it as such?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that your script is reading input "normally" via `read`, you can provide it input ahead of time with another program like `echo` or `printf` via a pipe:

```
echo Q | your-program-here
```

A more complex example could be:

```
(echo 1; echo thing2; echo yes; echo Q) | your-program-here
```

And even more complex scripting of automatic input can be done with programs like [expect](/questions/tagged/expect).

Answer (score 1):

To make sure that the command won't wait for interactive input, all it takes is to redirect its input from somewhere. Most programs like the one you describe exit once they reach the end of the standard input, so if you don't want the program to do anything except its initial job, pass it empty input.

```
thatcommand </dev/null
```

If you do want to pass some fixed input, you can use a [here document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document).

```
thatcommand <<EOF
Q
EOF
```

You can include variables in a here document, too. If the input needs to be constructed more dynamically, you can pipe any shell code you like.

```
{
  # complex shell code goes here
  echo Q
} | thatcommand
```

I assume that the program reads from standard input. A few programs forcibly read from the terminal, so input redirection doesn't work on them. In such cases, you need a tool like [expect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect). Expect is also useful if the input that you need to feed to the program depends on some prior output.

Comment: It's indeed working well in my case and it's actually exactly what I needed, for the command to stop ASAP.